# Script/command to merge 3 files retaining last file name

Tags: shell, unix, merge, rename, ksh

I have requirement where i have multiple files (header file, trailer file and data file) need to merge into one file retaining filename.

input files

```
WP2024916_191_FACETS_DAILY_CLAIMS_EXTRACT_20171110094055_7_1.TXT (Header file)
WP2024916_191_FACETS_DAILY_CLAIMS_EXTRACT_20171110094055_7_2.TXT  (data file)
WP2024916_191_FACETS_DAILY_CLAIMS_EXTRACT_20171110094055_7_3.TXT  (trailer file)

WP2024078_191_FACETS_DAILY_CLAIMS_EXTRACT_20171110094055_3_1.TXT (Header file)
WP2024078_191_FACETS_DAILY_CLAIMS_EXTRACT_20171110094055_3_2.TXT  (data file)
WP2024078_191_FACETS_DAILY_CLAIMS_EXTRACT_20171110094055_3_3.TXT  (trailer file)
```

output file should have data from files in same order and file name should be like.

```
WP2024916_191_FACETS_DAILY_CLAIMS_EXTRACT_20171110094055_7.TXT
WP2024078_191_FACETS_DAILY_CLAIMS_EXTRACT_20171110094055_3.TXT
```

need quick help to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you mean to create a shell script? How far have you come? Include your script in your question.

Comment: This would be a useful use of `cat`

Comment: i tried this                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                  
ls | awk -F '_' '!x[$1]++{print $1}' | while read -r line
do
    cat $line >> $line\.txt
done              it creates temp file with correct data,but i need file name to be renamed as i mentioned above and remove existing files. keep only final files.

Comment: edit your question and include your sample code (ie, move **from** the comment block, **to** the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all filenames are of the format displayed in your question (ie, 9 fields separated by single underscores) ...

Some sample data:

```
$ for f in WP*_?_?.TXT
do
    echo "+++++++ $f"
    cat $f
    echo ""
done

+++++++ WP2024078_191_FACETS_DAILY_CLAIMS_EXTRACT_20171110094055_3_1.TXT
2024916 header

+++++++ WP2024078_191_FACETS_DAILY_CLAIMS_EXTRACT_20171110094055_3_2.TXT
2024916 data

+++++++ WP2024078_191_FACETS_DAILY_CLAIMS_EXTRACT_20171110094055_3_3.TXT
2024916 trailer

+++++++ WP2024916_191_FACETS_DAILY_CLAIMS_EXTRACT_20171110094055_7_1.TXT
2024078 header

+++++++ WP2024916_191_FACETS_DAILY_CLAIMS_EXTRACT_20171110094055_7_2.TXT
2024078 data

+++++++ WP2024916_191_FACETS_DAILY_CLAIMS_EXTRACT_20171110094055_7_3.TXT
2024078 trailer
```

For this simplistic case I've opted to use `cut` instead of `awk` (a little less typing) to extract the common/base file prefixes:

```
$ ls WP*_?_?.TXT | cut -d"_" -f1-8 | sort -u | while read -r fprefix
do
    # concatenate source files
    cat ${fprefix}_[123].TXT > ${fprefix}.TXT

    # display concatenated files
    echo "+++++++ ${fprefix}.TXT"
    cat ${fprefix}.TXT
    echo ""
done

+++++++ WP2024078_191_FACETS_DAILY_CLAIMS_EXTRACT_20171110094055_3.TXT
2024916 header
2024916 data
2024916 trailer

+++++++ WP2024916_191_FACETS_DAILY_CLAIMS_EXTRACT_20171110094055_7.TXT
2024078 header
2024078 data
2024078 trailer
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. it worked, only small change i did is removed WP from ls command as i can have file name starting with other letters too..one more thing i wanted to add here is i want to remove 3 source files and keep only final file..how can i remove that..?

Comment: if `${fprefix}` is correct, you could remove the 3x source files with something like: `rm ${fprefix}_?_?.TXT`

Comment: Thanks again for your great help...you are genius !!! You made my day !!!!!!  here is the final code i am using *************************************************                                                                                                          
    ls *_?_?.TXT | cut -d"_" -f1-8 | sort -u | while read -r fprefix
do
    # concatenate source files
    cat ${fprefix}_[123].TXT > ${fprefix}.TXT

    # display concatenated files
    echo "+++++++ ${fprefix}.TXT"
    cat ${fprefix}.TXT
 rm ${fprefix}_?.TXT
    echo ""
done
******************************************

Answer (score 0):

```
ls *_?_?.TXT |  while read -r filename
do
    # concatenate source files
    cat $filename >> ${filename%_*}.TXT
    rm $filename
done
```

Add file(s) content to target file where the the numbering part is cut off.

No need for `cut` and `sort`, but does not overwrite existing target files.